# Error while generating grpc files (--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.)

Tags: macos, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protoc

I’m trying to run the following command to generate grpc files:

```
protoc --proto_path=$PROTO_PATH --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$PLUGIN_GRPC --grpc_out=$OUT/grpc $PROTO_FILES
```

This results in the following error:
**/Users/MYUSERNAME/Downloads/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.48.1-osx-aarch_64.exe: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.**

I made sure the file from the error message is located at that path and has also the correct permissions.

> -rwxrwxrwx@  1 MYUSERNAME  staff    6334176 10 Aug 00:03 protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.48.1-osx-aarch_64.exe

I also tried running the command as sudo.

Generating java or kotlin files with `--java_out=$OUT/java --kotlin_out=$OUT/kotlin`

works perfectly fine, so the problem is `--grpc_out=$OUT/grpc`

I also downloaded multiple versions of the protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.48.1-osx-aarch_64.exe file but it always results in the same error. I also tried replacing all path variables (e.g. $PROTO_PATH) with their corresponding values, without any effect. I’m using MacBook with M1Pro chip.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that M1 Macs aren't supported. They have copied over the osx-x86_64 binary and renamed it for osx-aarch_64 as a workaround to make it easier to run with [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861). See  [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/8557) for where that change was made and [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7690) for the full conversation about supporting M1 Macs.